# Does adding const affect overriding

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a method1 in the parent class and I want to override it in a subclass. Does adding const affect the overriding? For example,

```
int Subclass::method1(const int a)const {...}
```

Does this override

```
int Parentclass::method1(int a) {...}
```

correctly?

Comment: I would expect it not to compile

Comment: In modern C++ you can add the `override` keyword when you experiment so the compiler can warn you if the function doesn't override.

Comment: The originally listed duplicates are wrong, because they involve member function constness and this question asks about top-level const on a function argument.

Comment: Luckily I can add a more relevant function to the duplication list.

Comment: The `const` for a method changes the signature.  The two methods are different because of both the `const`.